# Dropwizard @Timer annotation does not work for classes other than resources

Tags: jmx, dropwizard, metrics

I am using `JMX` reporting for my dropwizard application. I initialize it as:

```
JmxReporter.forRegistry(this.registry).convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS).build().start()
```

When I use the `@Timed` annotation, the methods in the resources are timed and metrics are reported. However, all the other classes that use `@Timed` annotation are not metered (or the metrics are not pushed). I checked this by starting jconsole and listing the beans pushed to `JMX` server.

How to get the `@Timed` annotation to work with other classes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using com.palominolabs.metrics:metrics-guice worked.